# How to pre .bind() value to component's method in Angular 2 template

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a situation where I want to use `myMethod(param1, param2)` in Angular 2 template with pre bound value like `(customEvent)="myMethod.bind(this, "value")"`.

The `(customEvent)` emits some value which is ok, the problem is the `this` binding. What is the best way to access component's instance inside of it's template ? What comes to mind is to store component's `this` in `self: MyComponent` variable during instantiation in constructor. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Typescript you can define a method to bind "this" to the component:

```
myMethod = () => {
    console.log(this);
}
```

"this" will be your component

Comment: This would work but then i have to define fuctionality as property instead of component's class method which is nit bad but i preffer unified code style

Comment: you can declare components's class methods this way, I think

Comment: Will try it today and let you know

Comment: This doesn't help in itself. The `myMethod = (param1) => (param3) => { console.log(param1, param2) }` would do the trick and then in template I can do `(click)="myMethod("preboundParam")($event)"` ... that being said I think that storing `self` reference and going for `(click)="myMethod.bind(self, $event)"` is cleaner... Is there any other way ?